# nginx HTTPS serving with same config as HTTP

Tags: nginx, https

Is there a way to share configuration directives across two nginx `server {}` blocks? I'd like to avoid duplicating the rules, as my site's HTTPS and HTTP content are served with the exact same config.

Currently, it's like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  ...
}

server {
  listen 443;

  ssl on; # etc.
  ...
}
```

Can I do something along the lines of:

```
server {
  listen 80, 443;
  ...

  if(port == 443) {
    ssl on; #etc
  }
}
```

Answer (score 323, accepted):

You can combine this into one server block like so:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;

    # other directives
}
```

[Official How-To](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server)

Comment: Ah, I had no idea nginx was intelligent enough to ignore the SSL directives if loaded over port 80. Awesome!

Comment: nginx is all sorts of WIN.

Comment: and if you have several sites at one server, it's worth mentioning that "default" is not obligatory

Comment: So elegant it hurts...

Comment: I believe this works best "listen 443 default ssl;" not "listen 443 default_server ssl;"
}

Comment: How do you configure 'proxy_pass' for load balancing using this solution?

Comment: not working here... "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port"

Comment: @goo You need to omit line `SSL on;` as sugguested by user below.

Comment: For some reason this does not work anymore in recent Nginx 1.10.1 (regardless of `SSL on` line existence). I was forced to split ssl and non-ssl servers to separate `server{}` blocks)

Comment: I am using both in the same directive in nginx 1.14, but nginx is not intelligent enough because over http I get the SSL headers

Comment: Is there a way to redirect http to https while still keeping a single `server` block.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 + Nginx 1.18.0 keep warning with 404 on 80 but 443 works fine.

Answer (score 95):

To clarify the accepted answer, you need to omit

```
SSL on;
```

and you just need the following for nginx version after 0.8.21

```
listen 443 ssl;
```

Reference:

[Nginx Docs - Configuring A single HTTP/HTTPS server](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server)

Comment: Thank you! I could not figure out why nothing on http was working. Removing SSL on; worked.

Answer (score 32):

I don't know of a way like you suggest, but there's certainly an easy and maintainable way.

Move common server settings into a separate file, i.e. "serverFoo.conf" and then `include` it in separate `server {}` blocks like so:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    include serverFoo.conf;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    include serverFoo.conf;
}
```

Comment: +1 = works for me. (Couldn't get it to work with the other method.)

Comment: Also, the other example doesn't account for 'proxy_pass' if acting as a load balancer.

Comment: This option is great if your `server_name` is different for each port

Comment: Don't use ssl on, use ```listen 443 ssl;``` from now one.

Comment: This seems to be the only solution that is working with recent nginx 1.10.1. For some reason two `listen` lines are not interpreted correctly, but moving them to separate `server{}` fixes it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 12):

Expanding on the already helpful answers, here is a more complete example:

```
server {

    # Listen on port 80 and 443
    # on both IPv4 and IPv6
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on ssl;

    # Set website folder
    root /path/to/your/website;

    # Enable SSL
    ssl_certificate your-cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key your-cert.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
}
```

Comment: I know this is a pretty old answer, but as it's very complete I just wanted to point out for others who may use it that you should disable the SSLv3 protocol as its vulnerable to the POODLE vulnerability: https://disablessl3.com/

Instead use:

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

Answer (score 6):

Just to add to Igor/Jauder's post, if you're listening to a specific IP you can use:

```
listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 default ssl;
```