# How secure is this Nginx Config? What else can I do to optimize it further?

Tags: nginx, security, ssl, ssl-certificate, tls

So I recently setup a personal GitLab server and I am using the following config with full SSL. I tried my best but what else can be done to make it better? I mostly learned what I know about webservers from playing around with it in spare time so I didn't really follow any conventions. Please let me know about any comments and concerns.

```
server_tokens off;
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self''unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://ssl.google-analytics.com   h   https://assets.zendesk.com https://connect.facebook.net; img-src 'self'    https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://s-static.ak.facebook.com https://assets.zendesk.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://assets.zendesk.com; font-src 'self' https://themes.googleusercontent.com; frame-src https://assets.zendesk.com https://www.facebook.com https://s-static.ak.facebook.com https://tautt.zendesk.com; object-src 'none'";

server {
listen 80;
listen 443 default ssl spdy;
server_name gitlab.example.com;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";

ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/ssl/gitlab.crt;
ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/ssl/gitlab.key;
ssl_dhparam               /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
ssl_session_timeout 5m;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/CA/comodo.pem;
resolver 8.8.8.8;

ssl_ciphers  "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK";

location / {
  proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
  proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Ssl     on;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
  proxy_set_header    X-Frame-Options     SAMEORIGIN;
  proxy_pass          http://192.168.1.139:82;
  proxy_redirect      http://192.168.1.139:82 https://gitlab.example.com;
  }
}
```

Comment: My site automatically redirects to HTTPS when accessed with the config above. I got it from this thread: http://serverfault.com/questions/10854/nginx-https-serving-with-same-config-as-http

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `add_header Strict-Transport-Security ...` in `server` block removes `add_header`s from upper level.

`proxy_redirect` is superfluous. You just used default value, and moreover if you happen to change `proxy_pass` and forget to change `proxy_redirect` you'll get strange errors.

`proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options` is meaningless.

`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on` is strange, because you allow non-ssl connections.

Comment: How do I solve the add_header Strict_Transport-Security issue so that is does not remove the other headers? Also I removed proxy_redirect as you indicated. I thought the X-Frame-Options prevents the page being rendered inside a frame to avoid clickjacking? Also what exactly do you mean that I am allowing non ssl connections? The site is never served over http. It always redirects to https. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Put them all on the same level. `X-Frame-Options` is for browser and you have it in second line. There is no reason to send it to server. You have `listen 80` that means you allow unsecured connections to that server.

Comment: OK so I got rid of port 80 completely. Now it only works on 443 with ssl. Thanks. And I also got rid of x frame.