# Nginx Https issue http automatically redirected to https

Tags: nginx, http, https

I have a config file and have a site up and running. But there is an issue if we go to the non-SSL page then also it redirects back to https.
I have a site in Magento and it has base URL as http://www.cabletiesupply.com/ and base secure URL as https://www.cabletiesupply.com/ . Now I have not forced the admin to use SSL but then also it uses https:// which should not be the case. It should work normally as http:// . Which it is not. There is no issue in magento configuration.

I have created a gist of Nginx Config
https://gist.github.com/bhargavmehta/4280a5a77b48236da82db2ee52fdc7d2

I am making a mistake in the configuration. Can anyone guide me in this?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nginx HTTPS serving with same config as HTTP](http://serverfault.com/questions/10854/nginx-https-serving-with-same-config-as-http)

Comment: Not working in my case I tried

Comment: then please expand on your question, you seem to know that you are making a mistake

Comment: Hope this description helps now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the SSL config from nginx and enable it in 'magento' https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_ssl.htm

Comment: Can you suggest changes in nginx?