# Nginx: how to redirect all request from https://domainA.com to https://domainB.com? (and not only http ones)

Tags: nginx, http, redirect, https

I have several domain names, and I want redirect all of them to https://indi-ticket.fr

I have configured Nginx and all the request from **http**://other-domain.xx are redirected to htpps://indi-ticket.fr but not these from **https**://other-domain.xx.

Here is the relevant part of my Nginx conf:

```
server {
        listen         80;
        server_name
                www.indi-ticket.fr
                indi-ticket.fr
                www.indi-tickets.fr
                indi-tickets.fr
                www.indi-ticket.com
                indi-ticket.com;
        return 301 https://indi-ticket.fr$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name indi-ticket.fr;

    ssl on;
    ...
```

What is wrong with this conf? What `curl -I -L https://indi-tickets.fr` does not redirect to `https://indi-ticket.fr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://indi-tickets.fr is using HTTPS, which means it's hitting port 443, not port 80. Your port 443 config doesn't do any redirecting. It's [possible](https://serverfault.com/questions/10854/nginx-https-serving-with-same-config-as-http) to have a combined server block that handles both.

Comment: Note that without including the appropriate key information in the `server` block or having a wildcard cert for the server, browsers will stop on untrusted warnings. I believe the redirect is sent after negotiation.