# Set Nginx https (on port 443) without the certificate?

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, https, certificate

I tried to follow up this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/10854/nginx-https-serving-with-same-config-as-http) as much as possible but I am always getting this message:

```
This site can’t be reached

example.com unexpectedly closed the connection.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
ReloadHIDE DETAILS
```

in Chrome.

The part of the configuration I am having is this:

```
server {   

   listen  80;
   listen 443 default_server ssl;
   #ssl on;

    server_name example.com   www.example.com;
```

This is for my test website example.com on my local 127.0.0.1 computer.

Comment: The thread you mentioned is not for setting https without a certificate. If you want https, you need a certificate.

Comment: Thanks, @Drifter104, I solved the problem using the self-signed certificates.

Comment: I don' think the people answering here understand the use case. If people hit your IP address on port 443 using a different URL they will get served the WRONG page in NGINX. I have the same question specifically, because I made a catch all in port 80, but when a browser has the https cached, they route them to the wrong domain, when really I'd like nothing to be served at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to generate a Self signed certificate or you could look into the Let's Encrypt project to get a free and publicly trusted cert.

HTTPS is for secure traffic, and you can't do the encryption without the cert for the public and private keys.

Adding a link:
https://letsencrypt.org/